# Can't test connected component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I have the next issue:
before each test cases I create an container

```
const container = shallow(<Provider store={mockStore}><ReportButton{...mockProps}/></Provider>).dive();
```

So, when I'm trying to find() some elements, to simulate event, I get an error.

In snapshot displayed component itself, but not inner markup.

```
<ReportButton
  category={Array []}
  count={100}
  dataId=""
  filter={Object {}}
  fullReport={false}
  isEmpty={false}
  loading={false}
  period_tariff_is_active={true}
  type=""
/>
```

And I simply can't get inside the component.

One simple solution: as the Redux DOCS advised, testing component without wrapping in Provider.
So, you just need add named export for your component, as this done bellow

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReportButton);
export {ReportButton};
```

Congratulations, now you can test your component.

But if you use react-redux hooks (useSelect e.g.), then this trick will not be work, because your component will be wrapped in connect automaticly. And you will export component like that:

```
export default ReportButton;
```

So the issue came back.
And I don't know, how to fix it.

List of used packages:

```
"react": "^16.9.0",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"react-redux": "^7.1.1",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
```

Comment: did you try to use `import { mount } from 'enzyme';` `const container = mount(<Provider store={mockStore}><ReportButton{...mockProps}/></Provider>);`

Comment: Yep, and my snapshot look like this


`exports[Report Button should render component without crashing 1] = undefined;`

Answer (score 0):

I ones tested a Custom provider with enzyme. And the test looked like:

```
wrapper = Enzyme.shallow(
      <StorageProvider storage={storageMock}>
        <StorageContext.Consumer>
          {(storage: StorageService | null): React.ReactElement => 

            <HelperComponent storage={storage} />}

        </StorageContext.Consumer>
      </StorageProvider>,
    );

expect(
  wrapper
    .dive()
    .find(StorageContext.Consumer)
    .dive()
    .find(HelperComponent),
  ).toHaveLength(1);
```

So you may try to use [.dive](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html).

---

Another solution that I can suggest is testing using `@testing-library/react` as in my opinion is easier and interesting to test a component behavior that concrete implementation.

Comment: Try `.dive().find(ReportButton).dive()` to dive deeper

Comment: With dive() I can go down only to level ReportButton.
And when I try this 

`expect(container.find(ReportButton).dive().find('.button').length).toEqual(1);`

I get an error.

It's possible to use the @testing-library/react but their selectors really not suitable, and hanging data-testId on target elements looks like not good idea